# Play Framework unable to load webjars-play dependency

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I would like to add bootstrap 3 to my play 2.3 project, however play is not able to find the webjars-play dependency.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.webjars#webjars-play_2.11;2.3-M1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I have tried the following versions:

**2.3-M1**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3-M1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.0.2"
)
```

**2.2.1-2**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.1-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.0.2"
)
```

**2.1.0-2**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.1.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.0.2"
)
```

Is there a new version available that i cannot seem to find? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that 2.3-M1 was not cross-compiled for Scala 2.11, which you seem to be using for your project given that it's trying to resolve: org.webjars#webjars-play_**2.11**;2.3-M1.

2.3.0 has been released though, and has been cross-compiled to Scala 2.11.0, so change your dependency to this:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0"
```